# Set <View> in react-native-banner-carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native-banner-carousel` library for carousel but I need [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz42J.png) type of view and I tried to change height-width, padding-margin, etc. but failed and getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYBee.png) all time anyone know to do please help.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
    export default class Demo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        };
    }

    renderView(data, index) {
        return (
            <View key={index} style={{  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <View style={{height: 100, width: Dimensions.get("window").width - 150, backgroundColor: "pink" }}></View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={s.container}>
                <View style={s.bg_img}>
                    <Image 
                        source={Images.app_bg.bg}
                        style={s.img}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={{position: 'absolute', width: '100%'}}>
                    <View style={{width: '100%', marginTop: 20, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Carousel
                            autoplay={true}
                            loop
                            index={0}
                            showsPageIndicator={true}
                            pageSize={width}
                            pageIndicatorOffset={17}
                            activePageIndicatorStyle={s.activeIndicator}
                            pageIndicatorStyle={s.pageIndicator}
                        >
                            {this.state.data.map((data, index) => this.renderView(data, index))}
                        </Carousel>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Tim please refer my updated question